# Is it possible to loop over a computed Array in Emberjs?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to loop over a computed property array in handlebars. In this example, I can do it for an ordinary array, but not a computed array:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh7Qr/

What should the right syntax be to loop over a computed property in handlebars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you forgot to `return` your computed array and you have to add `cacheable()` to computed properties, which return an object and not a primitive. Otherwise you'll run into an infinite loop (see discussion https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/38) Also have a look at Gordon Hempton's excellent [blog post](http://codebrief.com/2012/03/eight-ember-dot-js-gotchas-with-workarounds/) about current Ember.js gotchas, among others regarding computed properties. However since commit [626d23f](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/626d23f6523ec6a6fe9f4daa63468888efca07f7) the issue with cacheable has been solved.

A corrected example of your code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/gh7Qr/4/

**Handlebars:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#each App.games}}
        {{this}}
    {{/each}}
    {{#each App.gamesA}}
        {{this}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    games: [1, 2, 3],
    gamesA: Em.computed(function() {
        return this.get('games').map(function(game) {
            return game + 'a';
        })
    }).property('games').cacheable()
});​
```

​

Comment: Thanks! I was translating from coffeescript, and forgot the return. The cacheable was what got me